# How can I send Lead event to both Pixel and Conversion API via an Elementor form on Wordpress using an existing set up?

Tags: woocommerce, elementor, facebook-pixel, facebook-conversions-api

I have a wordpress Pixel setup with "facebook-for-woocommerce" plugin that does most of the work for sending events. The plugin sends all events with both pixel (browser) and conversion API. The plugin has event ID (prevents deduplication), string normalizers and hash functions to properly manage the output.

I have an Elementor form that I want to submit data from. I have managed to use custom php and jQuery code to extract the data from the form and send it to a facebook pixel to create a lead event like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("form").on('submit_success', function(event, response){
....
    if (typeof fbq === "function") {
                
        fbq('track', 'Lead',{ ...user data... });
```

I was expecting it to be handled and sent via both Conversion API and Pixel. The problem is that this is only sent through the browser.

How can I send this data via Conversion API as well?

Comment: Are you looking to do it from the Frontend or server side?